# Spring Data JPA: How to find one column inside a collection?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have tried various examples but I could wrap my head around this.

I wanted to access a specific column from a collection. I am trying to get the Status of a Contract from the ProjectContract table.

`ProjectContract > ContractStatusCdtb > contractStatCd`

Here is my setup:

```
public class ProjectContract extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CONT_SEQ_NUM")
    private Integer contractSeqNum;

    @Exclude
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONT_STAT_CD")
    private ContractStatusCdtb contractStatusCdtb;
    // many fields removed.....
}
```

```
@Entity(name="CONTRACT_STATUS_CDTB")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class ContractStatusCdtb {

    @Id 
    @Column(name = "CONT_STAT_CD")
    private String contractStatCd;

    // some fields removed

}
```

and this is my repository:

```
public interface ProjectContractRepository extends JpaRepository<ProjectContract, Integer> {
    public String findContractStatusCdtbContractStatCdByContractSeqNum(Integer contractId);
}
```

Hibernate is firing query to get the whole `ProjectContract`. and I am also getting Class Cast error since I am returning String and not `ProjectContract`.

Can you please give me some pointer where I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of points.

1. You cannot get individual column. It has to be always an object of type which is 
   mentioned in  `extends JpaRepository<ProjectContract, Integer>` which is `ProjectContract` in your case.
   So your query is not correct as you can see from the error message. You need to change this to

   ```
   public ProjectContract findByContractStatusCdtbContractStatCd(String contractStatCd);
   ```

Or uif you expect multiple rows to be returned

```
public List<ProjectContract> findByContractStatusCdtbContractStatCd(String contractStatCd);
```

2. There is another option to retrieve one or more specific columns. For that You need to use Projections. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

Answer (score 0):

To get a single column from a particular table using Spring Data JPA use the @Query annotation to pass the hql/jpql that will be triggered when invoking the method.

So for your use case the code should look like:

```
    public interface ProjectContractRepository extends JpaRepository<ProjectContract, Integer> {

        @Query(value = "select cs.contractStatCd from ProjectContract pc join pc.contractStatusCdtb cs where pc.contractId = :contractId")
        public String findContractStatusCdtbContractStatCdByContractSeqNum(@Param("contractId") Integer contractId);
    }
```